# How to populate a TableView with plist content using XCode and 4 storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, plist

I had some trouble to figure out how to make a TableView populated with x cells reprecenting objects, a very basic technique. In my case I wanted to display images and information about different red wines. The tutorial in the answer below made the whole thing very easy, creating a propery list with an array of dictionaries to populate the prototype cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess that this tuturail will answer a lot of your questions:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Thank you one million times, that answered about 99% of my questions, now I can get started FOR REAL. Exciting!

Comment: I did this the way described in the tutorial, just changed player with wine. I've added the strings for the tableview (name, district, country) in the wine.h and wine.m and in the appdelegate.m. I decided to add the strings for taste, color, price, smell and so on in the same list, to use later in the detail view labels for the wine. Was that right thought of me? And how do I add image strings into this? I was hoping:

Comment: The best way to save the wine data, would be a wine.plist. This is an XML File. It is easyer to chnage, if you want to add, remote or change a wine later. You will reaed the plist at the start of the app and geanrate an NSMutableArray of Wine. Take a lock this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD

Comment: Thank you again! A wine.plist was actually the first thing I thought about, it seems a lot easier for this purpose as you say.