# How to use a plist to fill a iOS TableView in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, plist, nsdictionary, tableview, cell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to populate a TableView with plist content using XCode and 4 storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950876/how-to-populate-a-tableview-with-plist-content-using-xcode-and-4-storyboard)

I've done these steps:

1: Made a tableviewcontroller (WinesViewController)

2: Added a prototype cell with title & subtitle labels: namelabel & districtlabel. Cell identifier: wineCell

3: Made the Wine.plist with 10 wines (dictionaries) (Dictionary key = name of the wine)

The dictionaries are containing 18 strings with string keys: Name, District, Image, Alcohol etc, and 1 array called Price with Price strings.

4: Made a Wine.h/.m subclass of NSObject. The .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Wine : NSObject {

    NSString *wineImage;
    NSString *wineName;
    NSString *wineDistrict;
    NSString *wineCountry;
    NSString *wineFlag;
    NSString *wineFylde;
    NSString *wineFriskhet;
    NSString *wineGarvesyre;
    NSString *wineColor;
    NSString *wineSmell;
    NSString *wineTaste;
    NSString *wineSuits;
    NSString *wineGrapes;
    NSString *wineAlcohol;
    NSString *wineSugar;
    NSString *wineAcid;
    NSString *wineProducer;
    NSMutableArray *winePrice;
    NSString *wineFact;
}

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineImage;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineDistrict;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineCountry;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineFlag;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineFylde;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineFriskhet;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineGarvesyre;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineColor;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineSmell;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineTaste;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineSuits;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineGrapes;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineAlcohol;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineSugar;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineAcid;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineProducer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *winePrice;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineFact;

@end
```

And synthesized them all inn wine.m

And then I've tried different combinations of codes from Apples Propery List Programming Guide, http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 and answers from here, to fill the tableview cells with the Name and District strings from the plist as title/subtile. Now I've created a mess and confused myself, I dont even want to post the code from WinesViewController.h/.m. It's better to just start over.

Later I will add the images too, and use the rest of the info from the plist to create the WinesDetailViewController, but making the tableView seems to be enough to begin with.. Can someone help me please?

I want the wines to show a-z in the tableview, just 1 section to begin with and i will add sections later.. First, I need to make this ground structure finished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use:

```
NSDictionary* wines = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:<URL to plist file>];
```

That will create a dictionary containing everything that was in the plist. You can then step through the keys of the dictionary (which will be the names of the wines), like this:

```
NSEnumerator* keyEnum = [wines keyEnumerator];
NSDictionary* nextWine = nil;
while ((nextWine = [keyEnum nextObject]) != nil)
{
    // pull out the data for each wine, such as its image, district, country, etc. and
    // put them into your model object.
}
```

Comment: Seems easy, but I don't understand 100%.. Where do I put this code, is it instead of what I've made in wine.h and .m? Or can i just delete these files? and add it to the WinesViewController.h/.m? I'm all new to this so I'm a bit confused..

Comment: There are a couple ways you could handle it. You could just use the dictionaries you read from the plist, but I personally don't recommend that. What I was trying to show with the `keyEnumerator` is that it will step you through each top-level entry in your wines dictionary, and you can then pull out the other keys from those sub-dictionaries and make put the values into your `Wine` objects. So inside the `while` loop you can get the wineDistrict by calling `[nextWine objectForKey:key_WineDistrict];` where `key_WineDistrict` is whatever string you used as the key for that element in the plist.

Comment: I still don't get this.. Do I put the dictionary/enumerator coding in the Wine.h/.m (NSObject) and import to the WinesViewController.m? Or can I just delete the NSObject files and make it all in the WinesViewController? And why ContentsOfUrl if its content of a folder on my computer?
I would be happy if you can explain where I put the code and how I make the connection. I try to follow the beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 tutorial and just use a plist instead.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about your app, it's hard to say where you should put it. You want to get the data out of a plist file and put it into your application's data model (the `Wine` class). You could put it in Wine.m/.h. I wouldn't recommend putting it in the view controller, since that's mainly for coordinating the view with data in your data model. I suggest posting another question and providing more detail, as there's not really space in the comments here to discuss it. Post more information about what your app does, and maybe an example plist file.

Comment: Your answers have been very helpful, you are into something with the NSEnumerator and NSDictionary codes, I'm just not experienced enough to understand how to use it! I've made another question where I'm trying to explain more about my app, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039684/connect-a-prototype-cell-with-a-plist-in-xcode-4 if you have some time one day please take a look. :-)